# regex replace with groups plus optional group in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **What's working**: I'm using a regex similar to the one below for phone numbers ([the actual regex is here](https://regex101.com/r/Zc8cGh/1)) that can grab extensions
>   as an optional 4th group.  The regex itself is working fine for the
>   first three groups as shown below

```
"555-555-5555 x214".replace(/([\d]{3})-([\d]{3})-([\d]{4})(?: +x([\d]+))?/, "$1-$2-$3");
// returns 555-555-5555
```

> **What I'm looking for**: I can't find the syntax for the replace string to insert the phone extension preceded by a **x** ONLY if the 4th group is
>   captured.  In my real regex, the phone extension could be marked by
>   few different character designations which I would like to simply replace
>   with an "x".

If I use:

```
"555-555-5555 x214".replace(/([\d]{3})-([\d]{3})-([\d]{4})(?: +x([\d]+))?/, "$1-$2-$3 x4");
// returns 555-555-5555 x214

"555-555-5555".replace(/([\d]{3})-([\d]{3})-([\d]{4})(?: +x([\d]+))?/, "$1-$2-$3 x4");
// will return 555-555-5555 x
```

In the last example, I get the "x" (which I'm not surprised by), so I'm looking for the syntax to only add the "x" plus group 4 if something was captured.

Is this possible with String.replace?  If not, is there a more efficient way to replace these groups with a formatted number type once I've identified their parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String#replace` function can also take a function as a 2nd argument, which can be more expressive that a string.

For example:

```
"555-555-5555".replace(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})(?: +x(\d+))?/, replacer);

function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, offset, string) {
  return `${p1}-${p2}-${p3}` + (p4 ? ` x${p4}` : '')
}
```

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for more details :)

Note that your regex needed some modifications. Play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/rtJYTw/1

Comment: updated the sample regex, missed that when trying to simplify it, thanks!